# Proper MVVM Connectivity Management & Data Caching Policy

Tags: android, caching, mvvm, retrofit2, android-room

I'm developing an **Android** app (using **MVVM**) and I'm trying to implement Room DB caching for one of my models fetched from a REST API through Retrofit.

My question is: Is it correct to have my caching/fetching logic in the Repository as well as the network connectivity checks (using **ConnectivityManager**) to dictate whether to fetch data from the network or a Room DB cache? I'm asking since **ConnectivityManager** requires **Activity-level** Context to be instantiated and having it passed all the way down to the Repository doesn't sound correct to me in MVVM terms (and I'm not sure if it *could* work since I want to use **ApplicationContext** to instantiate it and I haven't seen people doing it like that).

I also don't want to try making a request to test connectivity because that'd ruin the entire purpose of using the Room DB as a Single Source of Truth for all my data *and* would be a rather useless request.

The only other way I might implement such connection checks and handle all the possibilities is through the **NetworkBoundResource** unofficial code excerpt from Google but I'm wondering if anyone else has a better solution. I'm also planning to save the last fetch time from the API as a property in my Repository (and update it after each API call) but I'm afraid that could lead to some tight coupling and overall shaky architecture. If anyone has a solution to how I might go about that, it'd be very helpful.

I'd be willing to experiment a bit but I don't think I can get in that headspace without mucking everything up.

Thanks in advance!